# Difference between two Psuedo codes?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

```
PrefixAverages1(X)
Input: X, a 1-D numerical array of size n
1) Let A = an empty 1-D numerical array of size n
2) For i = 0 to n-1
3)    Let s = X[0]
4)    For j = 1 to i
5)       Let s = s + X[j]
6)    End For
7)   Let A[i] = s /(i+1)
8) End For
Output: An n-element array A of numbers such that A[i]
    is the average of elements X[0],X[1], … ,X[i]


PrefixAverages2(X)
Input: X, a 1-D numerical array of size n
1) Let A = an empty 1-D numerical array of size n
2) Let s = 0
3) For i = 0 to n-1
4)    Let s = s + X[i]
5)    Let A[i] = s / (i+1)
6) End For
Output: An n-element array A of numbers such that A[i]
    is the average of elements X[0],X[1], … ,X[i]
```

So here is what I know so far:

The first algorithm makes use of a second nested for loop.
The second one is more efficient.
In the first, S is equal to the first element of the array. In the second, S is equal to 0.

What else am I missing? Any help will really be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Why do you have the feeling that you're missing something?

Comment: One of them recalculate the sum for each average. The other accumulates the sum and store the average. That's why number 2 is more efficient.

Comment: what do you want to understand?

Comment: I felt like there was more missing because my answers felt too 'simple'. I think nhahtdh gave me what I was looking for though, thanks!

Comment: For those of you who don't understand what I'm asking, I want to know what the difference between the two alogorithms are.

Answer (score 0):

In both algorithms, at the end of each iteration, S is equal to the sum of all elements from 0 to `i`.

In the second algorithm, until the first iteration, no elements have been seen yet, making the sum 0.

In the first, the loop that calculates `S` starts counting from 1.  Since it never looks at `X[0]`, that has to be added in elsewhere for the sum to turn out right.  So `S` starts out already including `X[0]`.  (This is safe even for empty lists, because in an empty list we'd never calculate a sum anyway.)

If you changed the first algorithm's summing loop so that it started counting from 0, then `S` would start at 0.  I'm thinking it wasn't done that way because the author was micro-optimizing, and didn't see the point of initializing to 0 and then immediately adding `X[0]` to it when he already knows it's there.